# how to pass dynamic parameter values from one module to another using switch Action in struts

Tags: struts

i am trying to switch  one module to another module using switch Action,but i need to pass some values(parameter values) from one  module to another module .

thanks and regards
maya

Answer (score 0):

The Request Object has attributes and parameters.  You can manipulate them